# session management in servlet jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm currently developing a middle level web-app in J2EE using servlets and JSP. It is just like a Content Management System. My website is working very similar according to my needs, but there are some *Questions* about *the best practices and the bad practices* for using **MVC** in J2EE.

Code for user to log-in to app is:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty sessionScope.admin}">
    <a href="/context/controller?action=add-content"> + Add a Content</a>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <a href="/context/controller?action=log-in"> Admin Login</a>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Java code in controller servlet is:

```
if (userDAO.isUser(request.getParameter("uname"), request.getParameter("upass"))) {             
    request.getSession().setAttribute("admin", request.getParameter("uname"));  
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/admin.jsp").forward(request, response);
} else {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("admin", "");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/content.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

For log-out:

```
<a href="/context/controller?action=log-out">Logout</a>
```

Java code in controller servlet is:

```
if (action != null && action.equals("log-out")) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session != null){
            session.invalidate();
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(
                request, response);
    }
```

I want to know is above logic for log-in, log-out and session management is correct?

And I'm also unable to preventing the user go back to secure page after he is logged-out, how can I set that?

Comment: Yes! for simple web app this session management is correct!